# Replace many commas with a space only javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace commas with a space like this:

If I have 1 comma, like :  `,` I want replace it with a space only.
Or in other cases, I have 2 or more consecutive commas like : `,,` or `,,,` or `,,,,`
I also want to replace the consecutive commas with one space only.

EX: `var x = "black,white,,red,,,,blue";`
I want to get `"black white red blue";`
How can I do it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: HI squint: It is just example :)

Comment: My point of asking is that it's often better to fix the problem at the source if possible.

Comment: @MinhAnh Example of what?

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using JavaScript's replace method using a regular expression:

```
var x = "black,white,,red,,,,blue";
x = x.replace(/[, ]+/g, " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vgmjqe82/)

Try this:

```
var x = "black,white,,red,,,,blue";
var n = x.replace(/,+/g, ' ');
alert(n);
```